# web3.js without installing a browser extension

Tags: web3js, metamask, wallets, myetherwallet

I want to make users not having MetaMask installed to use my dApp.

I thought MEWConnect will do the thing, but it requires installing an app at the phone :-(

Any alternative way? For example, MEW directly from the browser, without phone?

Comment: One solution is https://github.com/MetaMask/mascara but that wouldn't be trusted by users, and it is probably not compatible with web3modal.

Comment: web3.js without browser extension is simple.. See this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78608/can-i-retrieve-data-from-smart-contract-to-my-local-webpage-without-using-metama/78652#78652
But how should your user manage the account?

Comment: MetaMask Mobile Now Available on Android and iOS! 
see https://consensys.net/blog/news/metamask-mobile-now-available-on-android-and-ios

Answer (score 0):

You can look into https://app.gitbook.com/@arkane/s/widget/

Arkane allows you to easily integrate your app with several blockchains, whether you already have an app integrated with web3 or are building a new application from scratch.

Comment: Link doesn't work any more.